# How to show updated data with update of model in angular 2?

Tags: angular, pagination

i am currently working in pagination in angular 2. i am using  **ng2-pagination** for my purpose. what i have done so far is, i have shown data received through my api successfully. but when i click on next page button, data for next page fetched by calling again api for that page. but here **problem** occur, recieved data does not get updated in my view. can any body tell me how to update existing view with new data. my **pagechanged** function is,

```
pageChanged(event)
{
// alert(event)
this.p=event;
    this.httpService.getAllLaptops(event).subscribe(
    data => {
      const myArray = [];


      for (let key in data) {
        myArray.push(data[key]);

      }

      this.GetAllLaptop = myArray;

    }

  );

}
```

and my **view template**

```
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of  GetAllLaptop[2] | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:p,totalItems:GetAllLaptop[1] }"> {{item.SNR_Title}} </li>
    </ul>
     <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"

     directionLinks="true"
                      autoHide="true"
                      previousLabel="Previous"
                      nextLabel="Next"
                      screenReaderPaginationLabel="Pagination"></pagination-controls>
```

on initially call, i received data and show it on view. but on page change event, data received for new page but view did not get updated. how can any update this view?
any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. That was my own mistake. i just used

```
this.ref.detectChanges();  
  this.ref.reattach();
```

and there was another problem with my api that was returning same data on every call.